# Download a resource onto multiple Apache Servers? [Linux OS]

Tags: python, linux, apache

I am running a backbone server operations for my main server. The main server basically supports a iFrame to portal to the backbone.

I run the backbone at home on 4 Old Apple TV's that I installed Linux on and one Raspberry Pi I run the API on. The API switches from loading the resource from Apple TV 1, to the next (2), to the next (3), to the next (4), and back to one (1).

The problem I face is that it's difficult to have to copy a file 4 times across the servers. Especially if I am making a new page automatically that needs to be forwarded to the 4 servers.

Is there a way I can allow, say, an exception in Apache? or run SSH? And preferably a way to send these commands via Python?

Sorry, I'm much more of CSS and HTML developer then running servers.

Thanks in advance, *cheers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syncing files can be done a number of ways

You can either copy the files around all of the time to keep everything updated or you can use a network filesystem to keep everything all in one place.

If you decide to copy the files around I would take a look at `rsync`.
If you must have python you can do some cool things with [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/).

If you decide to go the network filesystem route you should take a look at [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll definitely look into the Network File Systems, but I wanted Python just so I could keep tabs on the Servers like stats or overheating.

Comment: Did you take a look at fabric?